# Dimension of File Block Execution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have this code for start application after download

```
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://mysite/myapplication.exe"),   tempPath + "\\" + sDownloadFileName);

                    try
                    {
                    string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
                    Process.Start(tempPath + "myapplication.exe");                   
                    Application.Exit();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    MessageBox.Show"Error, the file is corrupt");
                    }
```

but if the file (http://mysite/myapplication.exe ) it doesn't exist..
a file is created the same 1KB, start and return error =(
is possible block the execution file if it is small of 10 MB ?

```
                    try
                    {
                    string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();                        
                    if (tempPath + "myapplication.exe" == -10 MB)
                    {
                    MessageBox.Show"Error, the file is corrupt");
                    }
                    else if
                    {
                    Process.Start(tempPath + "myapplication.exe");    
                    }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `FileInfo` to check the size after downloading.

```
try
{
    string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(); 
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(downloadFilePath);
    if (fileInfo.Length < 10*1000*1000)
    {
        MessageBox.Show"Error, the file is corrupt");
    }
    else if
    {
        Process.Start(tempPath + "myapplication.exe");    
    }
}
```